# rst with optane vs ahci ubuntu dual boot instalation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Hi I'm new in the linux community, recently I installed ubuntu in my notebook an Acer Nitro 515-52. I already had Win10 in his ssd, and I partitioned my 1Tb HDD to install Ubuntu 20.04. The installation occurred fine (I think).
The Ubuntu takes a long time to boot and  after the start up, it takes a while to get faster. I know that this may be related to the HDD, but i was searching about some BIOS configurations and i realized that i had installed with the option "RST with optane" active, instead of AHCI. I changed the option, and it didn't had any impact in the booting time, if I install the ubuntu again with the AHCI option on, it could have any impact in the booting time?

Thanks

Comment: RST doesn't affect boot time.

Comment: Take a look at `systemd-analyze blame` to see what's happening during your boot process. Chances are good that you can speed it up by masking/stopping some of the services.

Comment: If you can have Ubuntu boot from Optane SSD instead of HDD that would be great for boot speeds. Be forewarned it's complicated...

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware to latest available? See also: Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702