# I was installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on 1 TB HDD in ACER laptop Aspire A514-54G. Installation is going fine but cannot make out which one is HDD

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, hard-drive

I have an SSD and and HDD both in an Acer laptop (Aspire A514-54G). I have Windows 10 installed on the 256 GB SSD and I was installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on the 1 TB HDD. Installation is going ahead fine but cannot make out which one is the HDD and which one is the SSD. Three partitions are showing `nvmeOn1p1` to `nvmeOn1p4` and one `WDC PCSN530 (256.1GB)`. Which one is the HDD?

Comment: Run `sudo lsblk` and edit your question by adding the output if the command.

Comment: "WDC PCSN530 (256.1GB)" does not look like a partition, but the identifier of the physical disk itself, and, given the size, I would assume it is the SSD.

Comment: Similar Acer. Issues more by brand than specific model. Bigger differences if Intel or AMD. Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702
Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected