# Cannot Enter BIOS After Setting Up Dual Ubuntu Boot (Acer Aspire 5)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

I have an Acer Aspire 5 where I removed the existing hard drive partitions and installed two LUKS-encrypted instances of Ubuntu 20.04.2. (There is no Windows operating system or recovery disk anymore.) I can access the F12 boot menu to select what to boot, and I can boot into my Ubuntu installations. But the F2 button to enter the BIOS setup no longer works -- it just makes the computer hang on the Acer logo screen.

(1) Does anyone know what might cause this problem and how to fix it?

(2) Would removing the CMOS battery and putting it back in help, and does anyone know if this type of action typically voids warranties on computers?

(3) If I can't get into BIOS setup but the computer otherwise seems to be working, is there any reason I need to worry and try to still fix this problem right away?

Here are some more details if it is helpful:

- After installing one encrypted instance of Ubuntu, I made a mistake and renamed the EFI/ubuntu folder on the EFI System Partition (instead of the correct way of using grub-install to create different boot entries with different id's, which I did later). This meant that the computer couldn't boot successfully. At this point (and when I added a second Ubuntu install), when I went into BIOS using F2, the boot order there started acting strange; for example, sometimes there would be just a blank entry, and other times an entry would show for the hard drive and a second blank entry would show. One time I watched as the name of the entry had some gibberish string that changed once while I was navigating on the screen. I could still access BIOS using F2, except for when I had an external DVD drive plugged in -- then F2 would cause the computer to hang on the Acer logo screen. But when I accessed BIOS to try to select the option to reset the BIOS settings to default, put the external DVD drive at the top of the boot order, etc. I ran into problems of unexpected behavior, the computer freezing, etc.
- To fix this problem of the computer not booting, I stumbled into the grub command line, I think from some attempt to boot from a Live Ubuntu DVD which didn't actually boot successfully but just took me to the command line. I was able to unlock an encrypted boot partition for Ubuntu, specify the kernel and root filesystem, set the initrd file, and boot. From there I was able to get the computer fixed so it would boot successfully in the future again without using the grub command line. I then installed a second encrypted Ubuntu.
- When BIOS was still working, I added a supervisor password, I disabled both Secure Boot and Fast Boot, and I eventually enabled the F12 Boot Menu. There was no way to move out of UEFI mode into a legacy BIOS mode.
- After installing the second Ubuntu instance, I don't remember if I tried accessing BIOS with F2 right away. The next day I realized I could no longer get into BIOS however; the system just hangs at the Acer logo screen.
- If it helps, currently in the EFI System Partition there are four folders: BOOT, ubuntu, Ubuntu1, and Ubuntu2. I think BOOT already existed; ubuntu and Ubuntu1 both load the same encrypted Ubuntu install; Ubuntu2 loads a second encrypted Ubuntu install. (Because of how grub creates boot entries, the "ubuntu" entry gets created even though I don't actively use it.) Each Ubuntu install has an encrypted boot partition and a second encrypted partition which includes the filesystem (/) and swap. Each Ubuntu install also has an unused grub partition. The Ubuntu1 and Ubuntu2 entries were created using grub-install --bootloader-id=Ubuntu[X] --no-uefi-secure-boot (the last flag prevented an issue where ubuntu/grub.cfg would be used even when the Ubuntu1 and Ubuntu2 boot entries were being used). efibootmgr successfully shows entries for the ubuntu, Ubuntu1, and Ubuntu2 folders along with "EFI USB Device", "EFI DVD/CDROM", and "EFI Network", and I can use efibootmgr to rearrange the boot order, delete entries, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you update UEFI? Does your Acer require "trust" on Ubuntu boot entry, most seem to need that. Whenever I have tried to create unique UEFI entries for my different installs they all use /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, not a grub.cfg in /EFI/focal as example. Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702
Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected

Comment: (1) Did you update UEFI?
* Because the computer only has UEFI mode (not legacy BIOS), the Ubuntu installer runs in UEFI mode. For example, when I ran "mount | grep efivars" during the installer it showed that the EFI variables were present. So I'm pretty sure the installer changed the UEFI settings. At some point I mistakenly changed the name of one of the UEFI subfolders but later fixed that.

(2) Does your Acer require 'trust' on Ubuntu boot entry?
* Secure Boot is disabled, and Ubuntu is still booting correctly now.

Comment: (3) /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
* Yeah, that is what usually happens, but when I ran grub-install for some of the UEFI entries I also used the "--no-uefi-secure-boot" flag which allows for using grub.cfg from another folder

(4) I can't get into BIOS to do anything about SATA / AHCI

Comment: If you have fast boot on in UEFI, that may prevent you from getting into UEFI/BIOS. Fast boot assumes no system change & immediately boots. You often can do a full power down or cold boot and then system will do a normal boot giving just enough time to press correct key to get into UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8

Comment: Thanks -- I disabled Fast Boot. The system knows I'm pressing F2 because when I don't, it just boots into Ubuntu. When I do press F2, the screen hangs at the Acer logo screen and I think I hear the hard disk whirring. I've tried doing a full power down, and waiting (whether for a few minutes or until the next day) -- I think that's what cold boot means -- but the problem continues.

(See next comment.)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I tried using the sudo systemctl reboot --firmware, sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup, the grub boot option "UEFI Firmware Settings", and running "fwsetup" from the grub command line. All of them froze the Acer logo screen again, so ti seems like they did try to go into BIOS / UEFI settings but the same freezing problem happened.

Comment: If it is a laptop, you also need to remove battery with system unplugged & hold power switch for 10 sec or so to make sure all power is drained from system. That is a cold boot. If that does not work then CMOS battery or jumpering total reset pins on motherboard should work. But then you have to redo all UEFI settings as they go back to defaults.

Comment: some boards lose their parameters when taking out on-board coin battery, and defaults will set in.

Answer (score 0):

I had also had the same issue before on my acer aspire 5 when I was installing manjaro. The system would just hang if you try to enter the BIOS using the <kbd>F2</kbd> button.

But I was able to enter the BIOS by restarting directly into the EUFI from the GRUB menu. And I also noiced some weird/blank names in the boot order.
Removing/reordering the EFI boot order using efibootmgr by following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205177/how-to-clean-up-bootloaders-uefi-entries-from-other-installs) somehow worked for me and I was able to enter the bios again as normal.

Another thing that might help is to change the vmd controller settings once you get into the bios. Go to the main tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and a few hidden options will come up. Try changing the vmd controller settings from that.