# Can't change SATA mode to AHCI in Acer dual boot Ubuntu with windows

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bios, acer, sata

I ran into some trouble in my Acer laptop which is Ubuntu dual boot with windows. For that I needed to change Sata mode to AHCI from RST OPAN but SATA mode in BIOS Information menu had become inaccessible.
I am unable to access both ubuntu and windows. My laptop is Acer A515-54G. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to access both ubuntu and windows?" Could you use them before? Did you flash a new bios?

Comment: Yes, I could use them before. I actually tried to update some drivers in windows that's when the problem occurred.

Comment: Updating drivers in Windows wouldn't have changed the boot settings. Updating the firmware (UEFI) could.

Comment: Problem is not that it's just changed but now I am unable to change it back.

Comment: I think you have updated UEFI firmware thinking that it is "some drivers".

Comment: Maybe, but what should I do now?

Comment: Sometimes an UEFI update reset to defaults & you have to redo your settings. I keep a list.  Some with Acer have posted they have to create UEFI password to open up settings (never lose that PW or reset to blank or you will have brick). And some model have to use Control S when in UEFI. Acer Aspire A515-54G -  CTRL S 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detectedAcer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702

Comment: I thought the same that UEFI might have been reset to default and also found about Ctrl+s option on Acer community but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Afterwards I found a method of updating BIOS after downloading from Acer site through FreeDos but that didn't worked either as no USB option appeared for bootloader. Then finally what I did was installing windows for the sole purpose of updating BIOS (one might use live USB) then used that to install BIOS which prompt that same version is already installed. After that Ctrl+s started working and FreeDos option appeared even after I removed USB. Now my Ubuntu is working but windows not.